# Travelling within the EU on UK passport expiring in 1 month

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, passport-renewals, customs-and-immigration

I am travelling to France and Spain via road on 31st August 2019 and returning on 13th September 2019. I shall be entering France via Folkstone/Dover customs either with eurotunnel or a ferry. My UK passport expires on 3rd October.

My question is will I be allowed to enter France and Spain with my passport having such a short validity date and with brexit looming?

Comment: What passport do you hold? How will you enter the countries? Are you already in the Schengen zone?

Comment: I hold a UK passport.  I shall be entering France via folkstone/Dover customs either eurotunnel or ferry.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the UK remains a member of the EU, you can do this.  The Schengen area has a requirement that passports be valid for three months beyond the anticipated departure, but this does not apply to passports from EU or Schengen countries.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was 99% confident my passport was ok to travel on as it's within date but wanted a second opinion.

Comment: @StevenWhillians I'm planning to edit this answer to add a citation to the free movement directive, in case that helps, when I get back to my desk.  In any event everyone is very clear that there is to be no anticipatory abridging of anyone's rights or obligations before the actual legal departure from the EU (furthermore, for movement of people across borders, it's likely that there will be transitional measures in place even if the departure happens without a withdrawal agreement, although it's certainly possible that the three-month rule will go into effect immediately).

Comment: Thanks.  I thought so bit just wanted a confirmation

Comment: This https://www.gov.uk/visit-europe-brexit might be helpful